# Trying to Color an determinate NSProgress indicator in Swift

Tags: swift, macos

Im trying to color an determinate NSProgress indicator in Swift with the system accent color (otherwise its just grey), but I can't get it to work.

I declare the outlet first

```
@IBOutlet weak var nsProgressIndicator: NSProgressIndicator!
```

Then the below code to set up and put 30 out of 60 in the value, this works great.

```
self.nsProgressIndicator.isBezeled = false
self.nsProgressIndicator.minValue = 1
self.nsProgressIndicator.maxValue = 60
self.nsProgressIndicator.isIndeterminate = false;
self.nsProgressIndicator.doubleValue = 60
```

but.. how can I color the NSProgress indicator, I basically want to use the system accent color, but any code I try:

```
self.nsProgressIndicator.controlTint = NSColor.controlAccentColor
            
self.nsProgressIndicator.controlColor = NSColor.controlAccentColor
```

Fails with "Cannot assign value of type 'NSColor' to type 'NSControlTint'" or similar, it seems to think you can't control progress indicator colours.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do it through the interface builder.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no tint/color option for NSProgressIndicators in the interface builder.

Comment: Help yourself by running a search for 'NSProgressIndicator color'.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I found those. It doesn't seem possible to color as the system accent programatically. I will have to find another solution. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: View Effects Inspector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it, by `subclass`  the  `NSProgressIndicator`

```
class AYProgressIndicator: NSProgressIndicator{
    
    var progressColor: NSColor
    var emptyColor: NSColor
    
    init(frame frameRect: NSRect, progressColor: NSColor, emptyColor: NSColor, minValue min: Double, maxValue max: Double, currentValue val: Double){
        self.progressColor = progressColor
        self.emptyColor = emptyColor
        
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        
        minValue = min
        maxValue = max
        
        doubleValue = val
        
    }
    
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        // set default colors
        progressColor = NSColor.red
        emptyColor = NSColor.green
        
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
        
        wantsLayer = true
        
        // Clear background color
        
        NSColor.clear.set()
        
        dirtyRect.fill()
        
        // Draw progress line
        
        var activeRect = dirtyRect;
        
        progressColor.set()
        
        activeRect.size.width = floor(activeRect.size.width * CGFloat(doubleValue / maxValue))
        
        activeRect.fill()
        
        // Draw empty line
        
        var passiveRect = dirtyRect
        passiveRect.size.width -= activeRect.size.width
        passiveRect.origin.x = activeRect.size.width
        emptyColor.set()
        passiveRect.fill()
        
    }
    
}
```

---

here is an usage example:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nsProgressIndicator: AYProgressIndicator!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        nsProgressIndicator.isBezeled = false
        nsProgressIndicator.minValue = 1
        nsProgressIndicator.maxValue = 60
        nsProgressIndicator.isIndeterminate = false;
        nsProgressIndicator.doubleValue = 30
        
        //  this is what you want 
        nsProgressIndicator.progressColor = NSColor.magenta
        nsProgressIndicator.emptyColor = NSColor.yellow
        nsProgressIndicator.needsDisplay = true
        
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
}
```